# Looking for mysql sub query

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query doubt.
I have a student table email is the column name, before inserting new student i need to make sure same email can't be inserted.How can i right insert and check in one query(using sub query).

Please help me to find a solution

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply do a select on the table first, and check if it already exists? Else simply add a `UNIQUE` index to the column you want to be unique, and you'll get an error when trying to insert.

Comment: I tried like , insert into student () values () where (select count(*) from student where email='test@gmail.com' <1 )

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to enforce it with unique constraint, but if you want to do in insert query, you can try something like

```
insert into student(field1, field2, email)
select 'value1', 'value2','test@test.com'  from dual
where not exists (select null from student where email='test@test.com')
```

Note :if you use an engine that supports transactions, you may still end up having duplicate)

Comment: insert into student () values () where (select count(*) from student where email='test@gmail.com') <1